# stored procedure gives incorrect output

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I want the flimname 'gladiator' not the other film name in the output

```
alter proc spfilmcriteria(@Minlength as int,@maxlength as int,@title as varchar)
as
begin
select filmname,filmreleasedate,filmruntimeminutes
from tblFilm
where filmruntimeminutes > @Minlength and filmruntimeminutes< @maxlength and FilmName like  '%' + @title + '%'
order by filmruntimeminutes asc
end

exec spfilmcriteria 150,160,'gladiator'
```

Output:

```
filmname    filmreleasedate                              filmruntimeminutes
Gladiator   2000-05-12 00:00:00.000                           155
Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire 2005-11-18 00:00:00.000   157
American Gangster   2007-11-16 00:00:00.000                   157
```

Answer (score 2):

You have error:

```
alter proc spfilmcriteria(@Minlength as int,@maxlength as int,@title as varchar)
```

This `@title as varchar` defaults as `@title as varchar(1)`

So actuaally you are searching not `gladiator`, but `g`.

Answer (score 1):

```
@title as varchar
```

It should be `@title as varchar(max)` or any length you storing in database

Answer (score 0):

```
alter proc spfilmcriteria(@Minlength as int,@maxlength as int, @title as varchar(max))
as
begin
select filmname,filmruntimeminutes
from tblFilm
where filmruntimeminutes >= @Minlength and filmruntimeminutes<= @maxlength and FilmName like  '%' + @title + '%'
order by filmruntimeminutes asc
end
```